# How to use HTML stored permanently on an Android Device as a webview?

Tags: android, webview

Is there a way to use HTML kept in the device storage as we do for XML in the package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use this HTML again and again then it would be better if you store that html file in assets folder and render in web view from there like this

```
WebView view = new WebView(this);
view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/hello.html");
setContentView(view);
```

Comment: Thanks! But how to render it?

Comment: I have edited my answer